# placing a footnote in a table

Tags: tables, footnotes

It seems that placing a footnote in a table is different a footnote in the text. Consider this table

```
\begin{table}
    \centering
    \caption{Simulation parameters}
    \label{sim-param}
    \begin{tabular}{| p{2cm} | p{5.1cm} |}
        \hline
        Processing Nodes &  UltraSPARC III ISA   \\ 
        interconnect \footnote{the text of footnote}        &  something \\
        \hline
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

In the pdf file, I see the number `1` at the top of `interconnect` but there is no `the text of footnote` in the text.

Any way to fix that?

Comment: This page consists of various ways you could do this: http://www.tex.ac.uk/cgi-bin/texfaq2html?label=footintab. Could you please have a look and see if one of them works for you?

Comment: Do you want the footnote below the table, or at the end of the page?

Comment: Ok. the `\footnotemark` and `\footnotetext`. Courtesy of kan's link

Comment: Do take a look at the (very recently released) [tablefootnote](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/tablefootnote) package.